# jBPM 6 How to assign process definition to specific users or groups

Tags: jbpm

I need to separate process definitions to users and groups

Example: Only financial users can start PayingProcess.

In business-central -> Process Definitions. I can see all definitions.

Maybe it could be a little thing but I'm stacked for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is now available on the master branch and will be available in jBPM 6.1, using the deployment descriptor.  This will allow you to specify which role(s) should be able to use a process.